# How can i design menu and title in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menu, desktop-application, titlebar

I Would like to create my menu groups in my desktop application as the one shown in sample image. I would like to know which control is used for it? What extra works we need to do on it?

A reference to similar one is also welcome...

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CollapsiblePanel or Accordian or TaskPane.

Check out .Net 2.0 SDK Samples, specifically Technologies\WinForms\TaskPane.